# Passing unknown type as parameter to a method then casting to that type later on

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic

I need to create a method that accepts an unknown type and then later uses that type to access an object.

A little more detail. I have a DevEx grid and I'm using GetRow to get a record. GetRow must be of the type of Linq class object to access the properties of the record. I'm trying to create a generic method that will allow me to pass in the type of Linq object and then dynamically cast the result from GetRow to that object. I will then get the column fieldname to access the properties like so (objectType is the unknown type):

```
void DoGrid (GridView gv, objectType)
{    

    PropertyInfo[] properties = objectType.GetProperties();

    foreach (GridColumn col in gv.Columns)
        {
             if (col.Visible)
             {
                 PropertyInfo property = properties.Where(prop => prop.Name == col.FieldName).FirstOrDefault();
                 ...
             }
        }

}
```

Comment: I just want to pass in the type. I don't think var would work in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for a way to do this with generics? Perhaps something like:

```
void DoGrid<T>(GridView gv)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (GridColumn col in gv.Columns)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then you'd use it like:

```
DoGrid<MyClassFullOfProperties>(myGridView);
```

Comment: 40 seconds faster than me.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. I was trying to do that in the class constructor but was having issues passing it along to this private method. I suppose I'll just make the method above public.

Comment: Now I get the error "System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] does not contain a definition for Where

Comment: you probably need a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file. `.Where(...)` is an extension method.

Comment: My bad...been moving stuff around. Thanks